# Table columns aren't appearing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Simple as the title says. They just won't appear. I don't know why. BTW, The table is added on a panel that has `setLayout(null);` So, I don't know if that affects it. I just really don't know where the problem is coming from. I'm completely clueless.

### DELETED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DisplayTab.add(table);` to `DisplayTab.add(scrollPane);` and make use of appropriate layouts

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still, when I added `scrollPane` it just gives me a blank page. :/

You're my only hope. If there are other ways to add columns, feel free to mention them.

Comment: This is my JPanel deceleration `JPanel DisplayTab = new JPanel();
   tp.addTab("<html> <font color=red style=font-size:20> Display </font> </html>", null, DisplayTab, "Display");
   DisplayTab.setOpaque(true);
   DisplayTab.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   DisplayTab.setLayout(null); `

So, far I actually only know FlowLayout and I don't like it. I didn't try it though. Any suggestion?

Comment: I used FlowLayout and it gave the result as viewed in the picture http://prntscr.com/98krwy

The thing is I want to set its location, because I don't like that way. Is it ok if I use multiple panels?

Comment: Use a `BorderLayout` and a combination of `EmptyBorder`.  Use `GridBagLayout` and a combination of insets and ixpad/ipady. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion

Comment: True. Your answer is the solution. Thanks. It was all about the Layout. But, one more thing. So, what if it was an illusion? at least it looks nice and the components are exactly where I need them to be. Unlike the layouts just messing up my display. `GridBag` seems to be the best, but the hardest to understand.

Comment: Not all computers use the same fonts, dpi, screen resolution and other properties which will make your "nice" layout turn to garbage

Comment: LOL! Thanks. I understand what you mean. I once created something with HTML and it looks perfect on my computer. But on other computers, it looks different. Even though, it's the same code.